# RadioGroup button spacing issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layout-weight, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

I have a RadioGroup with 4 custom RadioButtons, using icons as a new radio button, with no text.

I am having trouble getting them to space out evenly.

Below is a screen show and my layout code:

[image]

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton01"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_radio_select"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/cyan_clouds"
        android:button="@android:color/transparent"
        android:checked="true" />
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton02"
        android:background="@drawable/square_radio_select"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/cyan_clouds"
        android:button="@android:color/transparent" />
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton03"
        android:background="@drawable/oval_radio_select"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/cyan_clouds"
        android:button="@android:color/transparent" />
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton04"
        android:background="@drawable/thought_radio_select"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/cyan_clouds"
        android:button="@android:color/transparent" />
</RadioGroup>
```

You can see that there is additional space to the right side of the icon. Is there a way to remove this?

Comment: Hey Pablo, you should turn on the developer options to show layout bounds, this will give you more information on how the layout is actually applied.

Answer (score 0):

Set your Radiogroup's weightSum to 1. As you have 4 radiobuttons, you'll set their layout_weight to 0.25.

For more informations about the weight related mechanics, check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight) out.

EDIT :

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton01"
            android:button="@mipmap/ic_local_see_black_48dp"
            android:buttonTint="@color/red"
            android:checked="true" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Repeat this block for each of your checkboxes (with your RadioGroup's weightSum to 1).

Comment: hmm, I am using backgrounds (to get round highlighting issues) and changing the weight stretches the image :(

Comment: A kinda 'dirty' but fast solution would be to wrap all of your RadioButtons in another layout (say LinearLayout), to which you'll give the appropriate weight (0.25). Then, your radiobuttons will need to have their layout_gravity set to center.

Comment: Just tried that, setting layout_gravity on the buttons does nothing :/ Also, it interupts the Radiogroup :(

Comment: Answer edited... But I'm not sure if the Radiogroup's behaviour will work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar earlier in a linear layout, I think it can be applied to your case.  To do it I had to wrap my imageview buttons in a linear layout, so that they could expand but the inner imageview wouldn't.  Mines probably not the best way but I think it can work.  Here is that code.  Its not fully similar though. I was hiding and displayings edit texts.

`<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutProfileLinks"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">`

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButtonWebsite"
                    android:background="@drawable/website"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="onWebsiteClick"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButtonFaceBook"
                    android:background="@drawable/facebook"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:onClick="onFacebookClick"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButtonInstagram"
                    android:background="@drawable/instagram"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="onInstagramClick"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButtonTwitter"
                    android:background="@drawable/twitter"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="onTwitterClick"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/imageButtonYoutube"
                        android:background="@drawable/youtube"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:onClick="onYoutubeClick"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>



        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutTrueProfileLinks"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayoutWebsite"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewProfilelinkWebsite"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="7dp"
                    android:paddingTop="7dp"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@string/website"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextProfilelinkWebsite"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:digits="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm,:,/,."
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:maxLength="1024"
                    android:hint="@string/website_hint"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayoutFaceBook"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewProfilelinkFacebook"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="7dp"
                    android:paddingTop="7dp"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@string/facebook" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextProfilelinkFacebook"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:digits="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm,:,/,."
                    android:maxLength="1024"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:hint="@string/facebook_hint"/>


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayoutInstagram"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewProfilelinkInstagram"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="7dp"
                    android:paddingTop="7dp"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@string/instagram" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextProfilelinkInstagram"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:digits="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm,@"
                    android:maxLength="1024"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:hint="@string/instagram_hint"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayoutTwitter"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewProfilelinkTwitter"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="7dp"
                    android:paddingTop="7dp"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@string/twitter"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextProfilelinkTwitter"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:digits="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm,@"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:maxLength="1024"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:hint="@string/twitter_hint"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayoutYoutube"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewProfilelinkYoutube"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="7dp"
                    android:paddingTop="7dp"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@string/youtube"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextProfilelinkYoutube"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:digits="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm,:,/,."
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:maxLength="1024"
                    android:hint="@string/youtube_hint"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so here is a break down of how to get this to work.

For each RadioButton, I set a background drawable.

This drawable is a XML Resource, with a  Root, and 2  children entities, one for checked=false, the other for true.

They each point to another XML Drawable Resource.

This 2nd drawable defines the icon image itself as a bitmap, with tileMode disabled.

Bit messy, as for each single radiobutton, there is 2 PNG icons, and 3 XML files. But, it looks great!

[image]